# xml to xml field attribute transformation using ESQL on message broker compute node

Tags: messagebroker

I am new to message broker development. I tried to convert source SOAP over xml file to target SOAP over xml file.On my message flow source message discarded to catch terminal.I am not able to find out the problem

my flow : MQINPUT NODE ---> COMPUTE NODE --> MQOUTPUT NODE

If any provide solution on this that may me helpful for me.

DECLARE soapenv CHARACTER 'SOAP-ENV';
SET OutputRoot.XMNLSC.soapenv:Envelope.soapenv:Body.params.ORIGIN_TYPE_CD = InputRoot.XMNLSC.soapenv:Envelope.soapenv:Body.params.originType;
**

Answer (score 0):

Your first line is definitely wrong, but you should be able to see that from the exceptions you are getting.

The first line should be:

```
DECLARE soapenv NAMESPACE 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/';
```

An in the further lines the domain should be XMLNSC not XMNLSC.